# Pandas Outputting File Incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
                     Group     Description                       Type     Membership_Count     Members
0     ~Worker~ Start Group                Worker Start Assignee Group                    0
```

When I look at the output file, it looks like this:

```
Security Group^Description^Type^Membership_Count^Members
~Worker~ Start Group^^"Worker Start
Assignee
Group"^0^
```

I want the output file to look like this:

```
Security Group^Description^Type^Membership_Count^Members
~Worker~ Start Group^^"Worker Start Assignee Group"^0^
```

Any suggestions?

I am outputting the file using this code:

```
stuff_df_output = stuff_df.to_csv(
    path_or_buf = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'testing_output.txt',
    header=True,
    index=False,
    sep='^',
    mode='a'
    )
```

Comment: Having spaces is always a headache. Do you have the option to replace them with underscores or some delimiter else?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, there was a weird newline character that was screwing everything up.
Once I removed this, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = df.columns.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r,'')
```

is what you want